# Change the default font size for single account in KDE

Tags: kde, fonts

Recently, I got a new wide screen monitor and had to change my desktop size. Now when I log in, the font size for window titles, buttons, task bar items, etc. is too big. In fact, sometimes it is larger than the container holding the text. Problem is, this is a work computer and I do not have writable access to `/etc`. Can I change the font settings for my own user account? If so, how? Thanks!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Fonts are configured in system settings, not in `/etc`.

Btw. your problem might actually be a miss-configured DPI. Just force the DPI to 96.

[image]

Comment: "are configured in systems settings, not in `/etc`"… you got me lost. So KDE developers *did* dare call their users settings "system settings"?!

Comment: @Stéphane Yes, both Gnome and KDE settings are called system settings. This is actually causing file name collisions regularly :-)

Comment: Thanks. Everywhere I found when searching Google talked about modifying some file in `/etc`.

Comment: If you continue with problems with the size of the fonts, change the value in "Force fonts DPI".

Comment: the system defaults can be changed globally in `/etc` too.

Comment: It would be useful if someone could show where the config-files are stored specifically, so that commandline scripts can be used to modify these files. In my case, systemsettings5 (for KDE Plasma) works only partially; some widgets work, others don't. The font-related widget does not work and instead shows "The shared library was not found" which ... isn't very helpful and specific. Does not tell me what is the real problem. :)